# I have a problem regarding Wi-Fi in Parrot OS

Tags: wifi, parrotsec

I installed Parrot OS in my laptop a few days ago. Firstly, I wanted to install the Wi-Fi driver. When I tried to look for a driver, I couldn't find it. I turned it off. Later , when I turned it on the Wi-Fi was working. But a few minutes later, It was gone again. But something happened in today morning, the Wi-Fi was working again. I quickly ran `lspci` command and took a screenshot of it.

[image: Here are the results of lspci command]

The last one is my Wi-Fi (I think). I also ran `iwconfig`.

[image: Here is it:-]

- **Update** :- (8:13 P.M.) It is not working again.

Please help me accordingly.

Comment: What do u mean it's not working, explain more in details? Try to do a ping request or more still dons request. But since you just installed the is you can try upgrade your system specially packages inline with . WiFi

Comment: If at all possible please [do not post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Comment: you already have the line selected ... all you have to do is copy it and paste it into your post ... do the same with the file content

Comment: @geek I already updated everything.

Comment: @roaima I lost the text I copied.

Comment: @jsotola Pls work out with this. I need my wifi to be working again

Comment: You need to be more detailed and edit your questions with details explaining what exactly is wrong with your wifi

Comment: Its back again. This time, i ran `lspci | grep -i wireless` and copied it. Here is it:                                                                                                                   `$ lspci | grep -i wireless
                                                                                                03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev ff).`                                 My exact problem is that my wifi randomly stops working.

Comment: I also noticed one thing, the PC lags when the wifi works